# What is the different in the use of `round` vs. `__round__` in python?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, lambda, rounding

In python 3 this works:

```
Celsius = [39.2, 45.2, 37.3, 37.8, 89]
Fahrenheit = map(lambda x: ((float(9/5))*x + 32).__round__(3), Celsius)

print(list(Fahrenheit))

[102.56, 113.36, 99.14, 100.04, 192.2]
```

But, this doesn't work, Why?:

```
Fahrenheit = map(lambda x: ((float(9/5))*x + 32).round(3), Celsius)
```

Also, nowdays lots of python scripts don't use this old format `__round__`, I think for the reason to make the script look more clean. Any other core reasons?

Comment: `__round__` is a *hook method*. Use the `round()` function, it'll use the hook method as needed: `round((float(9/5))*x + 32), 3)`. However, `float(9/5)` is very much the wrong value, you want `9.0/5`.

Comment: But, why doen't `round(2)` doesn't work with float though. This is really confusing.

Comment: Because floats do not have a `.round` method...? What isn't clear about this?

Comment: I understand that floats don't have .round method - well the error message says that. But, it confusing that the way it works just changes. I think I am clear now.

Comment: @everestial007: `round()` applies to *all number types*, not just floating point numbers, which is why it is a function. Like `len()` and `str()`, etc. Python prefers a function when multiple types can support an operation, in order to provide you with a universal API that new types can adapt to.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: `round() applies to all number types`. This is most clear thing I learned here. Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `float.round()` method, no. You'd use the [`round()` *function*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) instead, passing in your value and the number of places to round to.

`round()` is a function because rounding is an operation that applies to all number types, not just floating point numbers. Just like `len()` applies to all sequences (not just `list` or `tuple` or `str`), and `str` to all Python objects.

Like all `__*__` dunder methods, [`__round__` is a hook](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__round__) for custom classes to override how rounding works for that class. The `round()` function uses it when producing the output, as does some other functionality.

This works:

```
Fahrenheit = map(lambda x: round((9.0/5) * x + 32, 3), Celsius)
```

Note that I did not use `float(9/5)` here! In Python two, that'd be 1.0:

```
>>> float(9/5)
1.0
```

because `9/5` is calculated *first* using integer division. `9.0/5` uses floating point division (because at least one of the operands is a floating point value), so gives you the right quotient:

```
>>> 9.0/5
1.8
```

You are using Python 3 here, where `/` means true division (producing floats even for integer operands), but the `float()` call is still just redundant there.